# Dispatcher timer tick function not called in anther thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread HeartRateThread = new Thread(startThread);
        HeartRateThread.Name = "Class1";
        HeartRateThread.Start();
    }

    private void startThread(object obj)
    {
        new Class1();
    }
}

 public class Class1
{
    public  Class1()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
        timer1.Tick += timer1_tick;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("timer called");
    }
}
```

I am trying to enable this timer_tick function fromanother thread as it is obvious in the code section of maInWindow. However, the Class1 constructor is called but timertick functin is not enabled. However if i do this on the main thread, everything works fine. Any reason for this.And how can I get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DispatcherTimer` can only work run on a UI thread. However, in your case you are creating a `DispatcherTimer` on a background thread. `DispatcherTimer`, internally tries to get `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`, in your case it gets dispatcher for the background thread, not for the main UI thread.

Do you really need `DispatcherTimer`? If you are not going to manipulate any UI elements in the `timer1_tick` method, then you are better off to go with a different timer, like `System.Timers.Timer`.

Refer to [this](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/10/timers-for-net-applications.html) to read more about available Timers in .net.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
private void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("timer called")));
}
```

Comment: But the timer_tick function itself is not called, how would this one run. Are you suggesting me to explixitly call the timertick function?

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested it, I guess you have to pass the MainWindow's `Dispatcher` to the DispatcherTimer on construction. Otherwise it will create its own:

```
private void startThread(object obj)
{
    new Class1(Dispatcher);
}

...

public Class1(Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer1 =
        new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background, dispatcher);

    timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1);
    timer1.Tick += timer1_tick;
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: this also works but I'll go with System.Timers as suggested downwards

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dispatcher for call  startThread method.

```
 object objParameter = "parametervalue";
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(
                                                                                () => startThread(objParameter)));
```