# Countdown timer in a thread using System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I need to run a countdown timer in another thread than the main UI thread. I can therefore not use the `DispatcherTimer`, since it only exists in the main thread. I therefore need some help to the `System.Timers.Timer` - I can't find any good examples on how to create a countdown timer on the web..

This what I got so far:

```
Private void CountdownThread()
{
    // Calculate the total running time
    int runningTime = time.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

    // Convert to seconds
    int totalRunningTime = runningTime * 60;

    // New timer
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => totalRunningTime--;

    // Update the label in the GUI
    lblRunning.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {lblRunning.Content = totalRunningTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");}));
}
```

The label `lblRunning` shows the countdown value.

EDIT: The problem is I don't know how to make a countdown timer in a separate thread and to update the label from this thread!

Comment: You say you can't use the main thread, but why not?  It sounds like you want to use the timer to update the UI, so why not just use `DispatcherTimer`?  That's pretty much what it's for!

Comment: @charles_mager Due to the design of the application, I cannot use the `DispatcherTimer` - it is not my decision :-(

Comment: The question is *why* can't you use it.  What about the design of your application prevents you from using it?  It is, after all, *exactly* the tool that you should be using.

Comment: As I understand, while you are updating a variable totalRunningTime, you want a web control (label) to be continuously updated. You are firing a Timer every second and reduce the variable, and then update the label. Is the current code having any issue, as I see you doing everything in the CountDownThread method

Comment: Wouldn't using a client side scripting like javascript a better solution for updating timer on a web control. Check following links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/429419/Create-Count-Down-Timer-using-ASP-NET-Timer-Contro

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/260124/Countdown-timer-in-asp-net

http://forums.asp.net/t/1085601.aspx

Comment: @MrinalKamboj It is not a web application - its WPF application :)

Comment: @Servy The main thread of the application is utilizing a `Task` to delay the execution of the main thread - the delay is vital for the execution of the program since the communication with the device will fail (Serial communication). I know it sounds dodgy - and it is!

Comment: Ok I misunderstood, but what exactly is the issue with current code, is it not updating the label in the CountdownThread() function. Trying to understand where is it failing

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Why does that prevent you from using a dispatcher timer?

Comment: @Servy I never said that, I have never used it, I am just trying to understand where is OP's workaround code faulting

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Sorry, that was supposed to be a reply to the OP; your names are too similar.

Comment: @Servy The DispatcherTimer only lives in the main thread - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630610/dispatcher-timer-tick-function-not-called-in-anther-thread

Comment: @MikaelKP And why is that a problem?  You want to do work in the UI thread when the timer ticks, so that is *exactly what you want*.

Comment: @Servy Yes it is, but the fact is, I can not use the main UI thread since this thread is unavailable at the time the countdown functionality is needed.

Comment: @MikaelKP But you're trying to do the work in the main thread.  If the main thread is unavailable, then *there is no solution to the problem*.  You can't do UI work if the UI is unavailable.  It doesn't matter what kind of timer you use.  Now, it sounds like the root cause of your problems is that you're blocking the UI thread, and you should stop doing that, but if you honestly can't (which is unfortunate for anyone using your app) then you'll need to *not do UI work* until the UI is freed up.

Comment: @Servy I use the following code to Delay the main UI thread `await DelayAsync(Convert.ToInt32(time[i]));`, which calls the method: `async Task DelayAsync(int i)
        {
            // Delay(value) -> value is in milliseconds!
            await Task.Delay(i*60000);
        }`

Comment: @Servy And the method containing the `await DelayAsync(Convert.ToInt32(time[i]));` have the `await` declaration

Comment: @MikaelKP Okay.  That's not blocking the UI thread; that's just scheduling work to be done after a set period of time.  It's not consuming any thread's time for that duration (neither the UI thread, nor any other thread).  So I'm not seeing the problem here at all.

Comment: @Servy My problem is I don't know how I create a countdown timer using the System.Timers.Timer - The code I attached is only some thoughts on how I would do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `System.Threading.Tasks` to schedule work on the main UI thread, the main UI thread is not blocked. It is possible to use the `async` keyword on a buttons click event and do some scheduled work, e.g. saving to databases. While the buttons click event saves to the database, the user can still use the UI and do other operations.

To recab: Using Tasks is not blocking the UI thread; that is just scheduling owrk to be done in some period of time. It is not consuming any thread's time for that duration - neither the UI thread, nor any other thread).

SO, it is actually possible to use the `DispatcherTimer` instead of `System.Timers.Timer` namespace, since no new threads are needed nor any threads are blocked.

The sample code for a countdown timer using `DispatcherTime` looks like this:

```
namespace CountdownTimer
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       TimeSpan runningTime;

       DispatcherTimer dt;

       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           // Fill in number of seconds to be countdown from
           runningTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(21600);

           dt = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), DispatcherPriority.Normal, delegate
           {
                lblTime.Content = runningTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                if (runningTime == TimeSpan.Zero) dt.Stop();
                runningTime = runningTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
           }, Application.Current.Dispatcher);

           dt.Start();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Start()` the timer and update/invalidate the UI every tick:

```
private void CountdownThread() {
    // Calculate the total running time
    int runningTime = time.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));

    // Convert to seconds
    int totalRunningTime = runningTime * 60;

    // New timer
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += (s, e) => {
        totalRunningTime--;
        // Update the label in the GUI
        lblRunning.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
            lblRunning.Content = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalRunningTime).ToString();
        }));
    };
    // Start the timer!
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: The countdown is not started - the label only shows hh:mm:ss

Comment: Your formatting is broken; I tested my code in WinForms with ``totalRunningTime.ToString()`` instead, see the edited post.